# Rewrite path to my files

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

I have a JS file that has a path to another script. If I do not want to reveal my directory structure, what would be the best way to obscure it?

For example, can I add a rewrite rule in .htaccess file and use that in my JS file or is there a better way to do that?

```
Current JS file:
URL_PATH = '/incl/pro/dir/files/server.php';

// change to:
URL_PATH = '/dir/server.php';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file in your DOCUMENT_ROOT location with following content:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^dir/(.*)$ /incl/pro/dir/files/$1 [L,NC]
```

Rewrite rule will take care of forwarding your request of `/dir/server.php` to `/incl/pro/dir/files/server.php` internally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would be a good use of .htaccess files to obscure the actual locations of files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to ask here.

A js file is executed on the client machine, not the server machine. So whatever paths you may put on a js script will never be executed on the client machine unless they happen to have that exact path.

A better alternative is to not include paths to a script. Instead have a ajax call to that script. You can't trust that whatever hitting that .php script is from a js file or from someone manually typing it in.

For example, if your site dir is at /incld/site/scripts/yourscript.php and in your js file, you can make an ajax using jQuery to GET the content of www.yoursite.com/scripts/yourscripts.php and parse out whatever you need or execute a script that is required.